# Birth and death process $M/M/\infty$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

I was reading about continuous time Markov chains, when I met for the first time the theory of queue processes. In particular, I considered the following situation which I found on Wikipedia, called [M/M/$\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/%E2%88%9E_queue) process. The model has transition matrix given by
\begin{equation}
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & \lambda &0 & 0 & 0& & 0&\ldots&0\\
\mu&-(\lambda+\mu) & \mu &0 &0 &&0 &\ldots &0\\
0&2\mu & -(\lambda+2\mu)& \lambda & 0& &0 &\ldots & 0\\
0 & 0 &3\mu & -(\lambda+3\mu) &\lambda &&0 &\ldots & 0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots &&\vdots &\ddots &\vdots
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Now, Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/%E2%88%9E_queue#Transient_solution) that the transition probability, assuming that the initial state is $0$ at time $0$ is given by
\begin{equation}
p_{0j}(t)=\exp\left(-\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\left(1-e^{-\mu t}\right)\right)\frac{\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\left(1-e^{-\mu t}\right)\right)^j}{j!}
\end{equation}
for any $j>0$. Actually, I really don't know how to find this expression. I was trying to write Kolomogorov backward equation
\begin{equation}
p_{0j}^\prime(t)=\sum_{z\in E}Q_{jz}p_{z0}(t)
\end{equation}
where $E$ is the space of states. Obviously all the equations are coupled and I actually cannot find a plausible solution. How can I find that?
I was also trying something different. If I write the embedded discrete time Markov chain $Z_n=X_{T_n}$ associated to the process, I could try to compute the same transition function for $Z$. The problem is that, also in that case I don't know how to procede in the computation, and I really don't see whether or not the two approaches give the same result.

Comment: I also noticed that the limit of this distribution for $t\rightarrow+\infty$ is the Poisson distribution I found to be invariant for the Markov chain, but I do not figure why this is true..

Comment: I tried to determine your Wikipedia links, and edited them in.  Please feel free to correct if I got them wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you checked any textbooks on queueing theory?

Comment: I do not have any good reference about that! I'm only studying this via some lectures from Università degli Studi di Milano which are available online! Any suggestion?

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link to refers to a monograph by V. G. Kulkarni for the result you're asking about - that would seem the place to start.